# Active records query is not working with a set of values which works for normal insert/update

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using CI and for inserting something into the DB, I am using active records method.

```
$this->user->insert($input);
```

is not working where `$input` is as below.

```
array(8) {  
  ["user_type"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(6) "manoja"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(5) "hippo"
  ["mobile"]=>
  string(15) "+91 94456594456"
  ["country"]=>
  string(2) "IN"
  ["state"]=>
  string(4) "1923"
  ["city"]=>
  string(7) "Bijapur"
}
```

but if the query is given using `$this->db` then it is working. I have confirmed that 'user' model (`class user extends MY_Model`)has extended 'MY_Model'.

```
$this->db->insert('users', $input);
```

above query works.

What may be the issue?. Please help.

Comment: What does the user model + insert method look like?

Comment: @Mudshark: it seems it inserts the array data which is in $input into user table. But it is not working here

Comment: Please post the code of your user model.

Comment: I think you didn't call parent class constructor in your model.

Comment: Have you created your own `MY_Model`? If yes can you please post the code otherwise your class must extend `CI_Model` just like this `class User extends CI_Model` and you have to make first character **capital** i.e. `class user extend MY_Model` to `class User extend MY_Model`